# How to recursively create patch file using diff

Tags: php, diff

I am on Linux, working on forking a PHP project. I want to create a patch file of the work that I have done, that can be applied to the latest parental code. Both original folder and new code folder are many subdirectories deep (so need recursive).

For some reason when I do :

```
diff -ur folder1 folder2 > newcode.patch
```

I don't manage to get the patch file including all of the new files, and it doesn't even contain some of the deeper file changes ( about 3+ levels deep).

Any ideas how to go about this? I've looked at Meld and Kdiff3...but they don't appear to do what I want either.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I suspect you have a directory structure that's something like :

```
folder1/
  text.txt
  level1/
    text1.txt
    level2/
      text2.txt
      level3/
        text3.txt

folder2
  text.txt
  level1/
    text1.txt
    level2/
      text2.txt
      anewdirectory/
        newtext.txt
      level3/
        text3.txt
        newfiled3.txt
```

In this case, `diff` will ignore the file `newtext.txt` within `anewdirectory/`. It probably also doesn't pick up the text of `newfiled3.txt` either. Instead it reports something like :

```
..
Only in folder2/level1/level2/ : anewdirectory
Only in folder2/level1/level2/level3/ : newfiled3.txt
..
```

Is this the symptom you're seeing?
Try :

```
diff -urBNs folder1/ folder2/ > code.patch
```

Comment: AHA! I had tried with -urBNs... but the answer lies in the trailing slash after the folder name, which your example uses! Thanks Katyhuff ++

Answer (score 1):

If `diff -r` is not working as described in the man page, it's clearly broken; however, I would create a local version control repository using the original code, and then, once you've committed that, commit the new code. Any version control system worth its salt will be able to create a patch between committed versions.

Comment: Thanks, I wondered about that...but was trying to keep life simple ;)

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the original project is under some version of source control. If so, there should be good tools built for that source control system that will let you create a patch. For example, if the source control system is Subversion (SVN), and you're on Windows, you can use TortoiseSVN to build that patch.

Don't reinvent the wheel.

Comment: On Aptosid Linux. But will do as Kojiro suggests, and set up GIT, drag in the original, then the new code.